# Online content - Using social media data to measure sentiment for a product - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, social-networking, us20130046760a1

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON determining the shareability of online content and generating customer relevance scores** - This application from a few independent social media "experts" seeks to patent the idea of...Obtaining social media data from multiple social media platforms relative to online content, calculating a customer relevance score that represents shareability of the online content and providing the customer relevance score to an end user client device.! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 8/18/2011** that discusses:

> - Measuring "shareability" of online content; evaluating tone of content and whether content is relevant to potential customers.

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

"**EXTRA CREDIT** - Calculation of the **customer relevance score** comprises calculating an **author rank** for an author by determining an influence for the author, dividing the **author rank** by a sum of **author ranks** for a plurality of authors to calculate an **adjusted author rank score**, multiplying the adjusted **author rank score** with three weighted components .
"

**TITLE: Determine shareability of online content and generate customer relevance scores**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Obtaining **social media data** from multiple **social media platforms** relative to **online content**, calculating a **customer relevance score** that represents shareability of the **online content** and providing the **customer relevance score** to an **end user**.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20130046760 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130046760)
- **Application Number**: US 13/587,789
- **Assignee**: Michelle Amanda Evans, Elizabeth Ann High, Russell Taufa
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 8/18/2011
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130046760)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method for determining the shareability of online content, the method comprising:
>
> 1. Obtaining, via a social media intelligence system, social media data from one or more social media platforms relative to online content;
> 2. Calculating, via the social media intelligence system, a customer relevance score that represents shareability of the online content; and
> 3. Providing the customer relevance score to an end user client device by the social media intelligence system.

In English this means:

> A method for determining the shareability of online content, the method comprising the following steps:
>
> 1. Obtaining social media data from multiple social media platforms relative to online content;
> 2. Calculating a customer relevance score that represents shareability of the online content; and Calculating a customer relevance score that represents shareability of the online content; and
> 3. Providing the customer relevance score to an end user.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 8/18/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming Identifying content that is to be tracked to determine the shareability of the content, tracking social media conversations of authors related to the content, grouping the social media conversations into one or more shareability classifications by conducting a semiotic evaluation of the social media conversations, and categorizing any of authors and social media conversations based upon the classification of social media conversations into one or more shareability classifications.

---

**"Determine shareability of online content and generate customer relevance scores" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful to you:

http://www.crunchbase.com/company/klout

The company `Klout` seems to have been doing exactly this since at *least* 2010.  The end-user  is the person being examined, as far as I can tell.  The score is complied across multiple social media sites and a numeric score from 1 to 100 is produced.  Does this qualify?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `Klout` is `Kred` which began providing a service nearly identical to Klout on September 30th, 2011 according to this article:

http://www.sfgate.com/business/article/PeopleBrowsr-s-Kred-eyes-social-metrics-precision-2298869.php

This uses a scale from 1 to 1,000 and has a secondary influence measurement (`outreach level`) that seems to highlight the second part of claim 1 even more.